# Validate syntax of mdx script

Tags: c#, mdx, olap

In my application I create some mdx scripts.I want to validate the syntax of the script, the same way the sql management studio does.Is there a class for this?

Comment: there is a parse button in ssms for mdx scripts - can you leverage that?

Comment: I want to implement the same functionality in my application.

Comment: is it possible for sql code? I would imagine if it is then probably possible also for mdx

Comment: I think I remember seeing previous posts of people leveraging some of MDXstudio when working with mdx ....